# Return all records that match array of conditions using CakePHPs find

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm currently attempting to return all records that match an array of conditions that I have. Currently I can get my code to work, but instead of returning all records that match an array of conditions that I've passed, it just returns the first one and then stops, instead of the four that I know exist in the table I'm accessing. This is with the all parameter set for find.

Here's the code snippet for a better view:

```
            $array = implode(',', array('1','2','3','4'));

            $a = $this->Assets->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'id' => $array 
                    )
                )   
            );

            var_dump($a);
```

var_dumping $a will just provide the record that has id 1, when there's records that exist for 2, 3, and 4 as well.

Comment: Why are you imploding the array?  Cake should convert `array('conditions' => array('id' => array(1,2,3,4)))` to `WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)`  You should check what query Cake is generating.

Comment: @kai Was used to imploding to a string for doing IN statements in SQL, thought it might be the same thing but guess not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the expected result.

You are working against the ORMs auto-magic. Passing a string will result in an equality comparison, ie `WHERE x = y`, and since `id` is most probably an integer, the casting will turn the string `1,2,3,4` into `1`, so ultimately the condition will be `WHERE id = 1`.

You should pass the array instead

```
'conditions' => array(
    'id' => array(1, 2, 3, 4) 
)
```

that way the ORM will generate an `IN` condition, ie `WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)`.

This is also documented in the cookbook:
**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions**